# What the heck is this C++ syntax called?

Tags: c++, constructor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is this weird colon-member syntax in the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor)

I see it everywhere in constructors in Qt applications, but I don't know what it's called. I'm trying to find docs about it.

```
Browser::Browser(QTextBrowser& textBrowser, QObject* parent /*= 0*/)
: // <- What
m_textBrowser(textBrowser), // <- is
QObject(parent) // <- this stuff?
{
}
```

I apologize for my newbness.

Comment: Get a good C++ book, you probably would get clarified instantly.

Answer (score 10):

[Constructor Initialization list](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.6)

---

Answer (score 6):

It's a constructor [initialization list](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html)

Answer (score 2):

It is a constructor initialization list. In your example, it looks like it's being used to initialize a data member and a base class.